# Regex for identifying and seperate multiple substrings from a single string

Tags: java, regex

I have an input string like

```
hello world , How alan_613 are you roma_222 all doing alan_611 ?
```

I want to use a regex to parse the `alan_613` and `alan_611` and store in one array and `roma_222` to store in another String array.

Curently I can parse and confirms the three strings' existence using

```
String re1 = ".*?";
        String re2 = " ( alan| roma)";
        String re3 = "(_)";
        String re4 = "(\\d+)";

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(re2 + re3 + re4, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE
                | Pattern.DOTALL);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
```

But how can I group them to two arrays without using two matches in one pass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to do this with two seperate passes. Each pass would look for the values you're interested in

Pass 1: `(?<=\s|^)(alan)(_)(\d+)`

Pass 2: `(?<=\s|^)(roma)(_)(\d+)`

---

## However

you wanted to know how to do this without the two pass solution. The best you could use an expression which places each match into a separate capture group, but I think this would be more cumbersome:

`(?<=\s|^)(?=alan|roma)(alan)?(roma)?(_)(\d+)` [<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://www.rubular.com/r/5jqKKvm1p9)

[image]

**Sample Text**

```
How alan_613 are you roma_222 all doing alan_611
```

**Matches**

In this example note how capture group 1 gets alan, or capture group 2 gets roma

```
[0][0] = alan_613
[0][1] = alan
[0][2] = 
[0][3] = _
[0][4] = 613

[1][0] = roma_222
[1][1] = 
[1][2] = roma
[1][3] = _
[1][4] = 222

[2][0] = alan_611
[2][1] = alan
[2][2] = 
[2][3] = _
[2][4] = 611
```

Comment: Well ... your desire can't really be accomplished in one pass. The capture group is the substring from your input text which was matched by an expression inside the round brackets inside your regex.  Read through this http://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html as they have some really good examples of capture groups.

Comment: That's a great question. Using capture groups is going to require you to do some post processing which would separate the data out from each found match. The multiple passes would be much easier to maintain in the long run.

Comment: Ok thanks for the info. Voting this as correct answer. Can you provide any example in particular which tries to do the same thing. that is comparing a set of strings against a parent string and grouping similar strings to arraylists,

Comment: Either direction is going to cause some overhead. Personally I'd go with the easier to maintain solution. And depending on the quantity of data your matching, you might not even notice an observable difference in performance between the two possible solutions.

Comment: And also one high level question. Do you think regex is the best way to approach this problem as far as perfomance is concerned? I am working in Java, Android to be precise. or should I go with normal String search or some thing?

Comment: I can't think of an example like that. I'm sure they exist. I do think that using regex for finding your desired substrings is the best way to go here. You could create a custom made parsing engine using other commands like indexof(), but this would be woefully slow by comparison.

Comment: There is a third option here, which is to just pull all the substrings you're interested in one pass, popluate one array, then use a custom parsing script to evaluate each array entry.

Comment: Yes. i also thought about it. but wanted to confirm if I can do this in one pass using regex only without extra parsing logic. I am planning to go that way if I cannot get it working in one pass